# This application is currently offline. To enable the application, remove the app_offline.htm visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, iis-7

my visual studio 2012 project work very well.I have many pojects.But just one today does not work.It worked yesterday and other day but today it does not work.I do not any things,there is no change(I look TFS view history I get yesterday files but it still does not work) but it give that error

**This application is currently offline. To enable the application, remove the app_offline.htm file from the application root directory.**

I look project folder there is no app_offline.htm

what should I do?

Comment: did you find the problem? i have just got the same error and I do not have that file either

Comment: I did'nt remember it but it is was problem abaout me not visual studio..